# Using wget to save sequential files as well as renaming the file extension

Tags: wget

I run a cron job that requests a snapshot from a remote webcam at a local address:

`wget http://user:pass@10.0.0.50/snapshot.cgi`

This creates the files `snapshot.cgi`, `snapshot.cgi.1`, `snapshot.cgi.2`, each time it's run.

My desired result would be for the file to be named similar to `file.1.jpg`, `file.2.jpg`. Basically, sequentially or date/time named files with the correct file extension instead of `.cgi`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this mean you get 3 files each time it's run ?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear. It creates a single new file on each run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably torture wget into doing it, but why bother?  Try

```
wget http://user:pass@10.0.0.50/snapshot.cgi
mv snapshot.cgi snapshot-`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S`.jpeg
```

This should create date-and-time stamped images like `snapshot-2011-04-12-081649.jpeg`.  Will that do?

**Edit**: OK, not too much torturing is required:

```
wget -O snapshot-`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S`.jpeg http://user:pass@10.0.0.50/snapshot.cgi
```

But most of me still prefers the UNIX way of doing it with small, discrete tools.

Comment: If you just want a simple date stamp, MadHatter's solution is the way to go.  I ran with the sequential incremental counter idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a simple bash loop and the `-O` option in wget.

Something like this:

```
i=0
while 1
do
  # increment our counter
  ((i++))
  # get the file and save it
  wget -O file.$i.jpg http://user:pass@10.0.0.50/snapshot.cgi
  # presumably you want to wait some time after each retrieval
  sleep 30
done
```

One obvious annoyance is that if you already have a file.1.jpg in the directory and you start this script, it will be overwritten.  To deal with that, you first need to find all the existing file.N.jpg files, find the largest value for N, and start at N+1.  Here's an *incredibly* braindead way to do that:

```
# find the last sequential file:
i=$(ls -t file.*.jpg | head -1 | awk -F. '{ print $2}') 
# if there weren't any matching files, force $i to 0
[ $i > 0 ] || i=0
# increment by one to get your starting value for $i
((i++))
# and then start your capture mechanism
while 1
do
  # increment our counter
  ((i++))
  # get the file and save it
  wget -O file.$i.jpg http://user:pass@10.0.0.50/snapshot.cgi
  # presumably you want to wait some time after each retrieval
  sleep 30
done
```

Really I should rewrite this whole thing as a perl one-liner but I'm tired and it's late so I'll be lazy.  Anyway that should give you an idea of how to accomplish this with a simple shell script mechanism.